# How to set up hbase on spring

Tags: spring, configuration, hadoop, installation, hbase

I installed Hbase on a remote cluster and success using the Hbase API to access the data. But I need to interact with the data through a webapp. Is there any hello world sample for setting up hbase on spring/JSF2 with necessary configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

A precursory look revealed this at the top of google.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-hadoop/docs/snapshot/reference/html/hbase.html